# Would objects really be at rest relative to each other in orbit?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, centrifugal-force, equivalence-principle

I am currently reading *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler (MTW). In the very first chapter on weightlessness they make the following claim:

> *“Contemplate the interior of a spaceship and a key, penny, nut and pea by accident or design set free inside. Shielded from all view of the world outside by the walls of the vesse, each object stays at rest relative to the vessel. Or it moves through the room in a straight line with uniform velocity. That is the lesson which experience shouts out. Forego talk of acceleration! That, paradoxically is the lesson of the circumstance that ‘all objects fall with the same acceleration’. Whose fault were those accelerations after all? They came from allowing a ground based observer into the act: the push of the ground under his feet was driving him away from a natural world line.”*

It seemed reproducing the offending quote would highlight if my question rests on misunderstanding what it says.

My question is this: if this is supposed to be saying that a spaceship in orbit feels no acceleration, being in free fall, then does that mean such a ship and its contents would feel no apparent rotational forces?

I would have thought that, given from a Newtonian perspective it is moving in a circle, objects inside would *not* act as if they were in an inertial frame. There would be a slight apparent centrifugal force. There would appear to be Coriolis forces. Am I wrong? Would no such forces be apparent if one were actually in orbit?

They clearly are talking about orbit - there wouldn’t be any point in the quote if it were just a ship floating in empty space.

Comment: You are supposed to realise that the Newtonian perspective is wrong. You should not talk about centrifugal anything, because it will just confuse you without bringing in anything useful. At the level of detail that the book is covering, we are ignoring the possible rotations, maybe Coriolis effects along with that.

Comment: Note that there is an unspoken assumption that the spaceship is not rotating i.e. its orientation *relative to distant fixed stars* does not change. However, its orientation *relative to the direction to the Earth* does change during its orbit.

Comment: Something to think about: if on an amusement park ride (a rotating frame), you don't experience a long-distance central force everywhere at once - you experience local forces, and the acceleration is imparted on you first through contact with your seat (or walls, or whatever is holding you), and then through the internal forces within your body. But if you are in orbit due to gravity, every particle in your body experiences the gravitational force at all times, and has the same acceleration - and you don't feel any of it (e.g. you're in orbit around the Sun right now, and also when you jump).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a Newtonian perspective the objects free-floating inside the spaceship are subject to (almost) exactly the same gravitational acceleration as the spaceship and travel on similar orbits. The walls of the spaceship do not "shield" them from gravitational attraction. Hence there is no apparent centrifugal or coriolis force on those objects in the accelerated frame of reference of the spaceship. There *will* be tidal forces, since the gravitational acceleration will not be identical in all parts of the spaceship.

Comment: Complete moment on my part, had been picturing a box with a string attached, but in this analogy the string would of course be attached to everything within the box as well.

Comment: One of the abstractions in this thought experiment is 'local' or 'small', in space and time, so tidal effects don't matter. Ofc, if you're orbiting a Kerr BH and don't make the approximation: tendex lines will ($\frac 1 2$ squish)$^2$/stretch you, and vortex lines will differentially rotate you.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is a spaceship free in a flat universe. Galilei's idea a bit elevated: Galilei considered the man on the top of the mast, letting a stone fall freely to a point on deck (captains head, e.g.). He successfully hits the goal independent of the ships constant velocity.

If the spaceship orbits the earth on a circle, the parallelly freely moving objects, orbit on slightly different Kepler ellipses, so they change relative orientation and their periods may be different.

What MTW want to demonstrate, is the fact, that everyday gravitational forces are the opposite of the obvious:

Fixing an object to the surface of the earth by its gravitational pull is really the permanent force of the ground acting on the object against the acceleration on the free motion, starting on the ground, and falling freely as if the gravitating mass of the earth was concentrated in a smaller ball around the center, as it happens on a cliff.

By Newtons actio=reactio at rest, the accelerating force is equal to the exerted force onto the balance on the floor.